# how to implement accordion transition with both vertical and horizontal direction?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, transition

I use svelte's transition:slide to implement a accodion transition, the demo code is simple:

```html
<script>
  import { slide } from "svelte/transition";

  let show = false;
</script>

<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button on:click={() => (show = !show)}>active</button>
    {#if show}
      <div transition:slide={{ duration: 300 }}>hidden content hidden content hidden content</div>
    {/if}
  </div>
</main>

<style>
  .wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
```

the transition it's work perfect in the vertical direction, but the horizonal direction's expand lose the animation, it's can be seen with https://svelte.dev/repl/acd001e268dc46dfbbf0c2fa97e8f3ac?version=4.2.7 .

it's very kind if someone can tell me how to implement accordion transition with both vertical and horizontal direction , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a new custom transition, you can read here https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#custom-animation-functions how to do that.

In your case, the way to do it would be along these lines:

```js
function wop(node, params) {
  const { height, width } = getComputedStyle(node);
  const { duration = 500 } = params;
        
  return {
    duration,
    css: t => `
clip-path: polygon(0 0, ${t*100}% 0, ${t*100}% ${t*100}%, 0 ${t*100}%);
margin-right: calc((${t-1})*${width});
margin-bottom: calc((${t-1})*${height});
overflow-y: hidden;
`
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help , it's work perfect! but I am confused with the css properties. I just use width & height to do the same thing , it's looked worse.  In my viewpoint , the clip-path is used to partial show element , margin & overflow are used to prevent element take full width/height to lose the wrapper element's transition. but I add margin-right/bottom: -x px  to a div , it's seems do nothing to the div self. what's wrong with my thinking?